# UWP AutoSuggestBox SuggestionChosen fires on selection of first item via keyboard up/down

Tags: c#, uwp

I just discovered `SuggestionChosen` fires when the first item in an `AutoSuggestBox` is highlighted using the keyboard up/down keys.

Effectively, I'm unable to pick anything beyond the first one on a list.

This works well for mouse.

What's the correct approach for keyboard navigation?

```
private async void searchboxaddpart_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        var dw = (Item)args.SelectedItem;
        ViewModel.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage),
            new Item()
            {
                Id = null,
                Description = dw.desc
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be doing the navigation under the `QuerySubmitted` instead of `SuggestionChosen`. The latter is generally just for updating the `Text` on the control. This way, the arrow arrays won't be interrupted.

```
private void searchboxaddpart_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.SelectedItem is Item item)
    {
        sender.Text = item.desc;
    }
}

private void searchboxaddpart_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null && args.ChosenSuggestion is Item item)
    {
        ViewModel.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage),
            new Item
            {
                Id = null,
                Description = item.desc
            });
    }
}
```